# How would i get Fancybox (jquery lightbox plugin) to work as a normal image slider notpoping up as a lightbox?

Tags: fancybox

Hi I'm using the Fancybox lightbox else where in my site and to keep things looking the same i thought id try and use it as just a slider gallery in the page rather than a lightbox gallery popping up on the page... the link...http://fancybox.net/

how would i do this at the moment I've got `

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("a[rel=example_group], a[rel=example_group1]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });

    });
```

`

in the head and i am also refencing some other external JS scripts that are included in the fancy box download

any help would be great
thanks in advance !

Sam

Answer (score 0):

... Fancybox doesn't do that. It's not an inline slideshow - it's a lightbox. It sounds like what you really want is an inline slide show with next and back buttons.

Try out jQuery Cycle. It does that:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/